# Retrofit using saved id in SharedPreference to POST update based on id

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have user id from login saved in shared preference that I want to use for profile update by send POST method to API but getting an error:

> Attribute value must be constant

UserService.java:

```
   GetPrefId callid = new GetPrefId(); //this is the user id source(GetPrefId.java)

   @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
   @POST("users/update/" + callid)
   Call<UpdateResponse> userUpdate(@Body UpdateRequest updateRequest);
```

GetPrefId.java:

```
public class GetPrefId extends AppCompatActivity {

        SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);
        private String idPref = sharedPrefManager.getId();

        public static final String prefid() {
                String id = GetPrefId.prefid();
                return id;
        }
}
```

API endpoint:

> apiendpoint.com/users/update/:id

:id is based on saved id in the shared preferences

I don't know any other way to insert the user id to the URL. Thanks for your attention and help

Update:

this is the UpdateActivity logic:

```
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
    updateRequest.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    updateRequest.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
    updateRequest.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

    Call<UpdateResponse> updateResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().userUpdate(updateRequest);
    updateResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UpdateResponse> call, Response<UpdateResponse> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(EditprofilActivity.this,"Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                UpdateResponse signupResponse =  response.body();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for inserting id in URL do like this

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);`
```

Update :

According to your updated question do like this:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
updateRequest.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
updateRequest.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
updateRequest.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

//here get your id from sharedpref
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);
private String idPref = sharedPrefManager.getId();

//and pass the id to your api function
Call<UpdateResponse> updateResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().userUpdate(idPref , updateRequest);
```

Comment: how I pass the sharedpref id to te "id"?

Comment: pls check my updateactivity, above

Comment: @Dwictator check my updated answer